# Does Windows 10 factory reset revert to the iteration of Windows 10 that came with the computer?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I can't find a clear answer, but I think the newest version of Windows 10 is causing a conflict with the factory drivers for my laptop's touchpad. It worked fine for day 1-4 of me owning the laptop, but now it is having some lag issues.

I did a factory reset, deleting all user data using the reset option in Windows, and the issue still persists.

From my research, it seems the factory reset installs the factory configuration with a "fresh" copy of Windows.

Is it safe to assume "fresh" in this context means the newest version?

Is there anything that could explain this issue persisting, aside from a hardware malfunction? Any tests you might recommending to narrow the cause?

Comment: Windows Reset using the windows image that exists on the system.  If you are using an OEM Factory reset then you are restoring the image stored on another partition.  That image is NOT updated when a new feature update is installed.  Can you clarify what you mean by "factory reset"?

Comment: @Ramhound Asus refers to the built in reset feature on Windows as a factory reset; I don't exactly agree with that, but they do. I'm not referring to reinstalling from an image stored elsewhere, as clearly that would not be modified by a feature update. Thanks!